# Javascript | Parsing error: unexpected token if

Tags: javascript, eslint

Before reading below, do note that I have only recently started learning Javascript.

I am interested in making a text-based survival game. When trying to subtract a random number of survivors from the whole, I attempted to write what I think is, *"A raid happens if the number is 0.50 - 1.00, and if the raid is successful, the group loses a random number of survivors between 1, and however many survivors there are."* However, when I write this, I get an ESLint error, stating: **ERROR: Parsing error: Unexpected Token if** I don't know how I would rewrite it, or how to reformat it to work, if it is at all possible. The issue is in the code below, on lines 10, 11, & 12.

```
//constants
var EVENT_CHANCE = 0.15;
var EVENT_TYPE = 0.50;
var FOOD_CONSUMPTION = FOOD_CONSUMPTION;
var MATERIALS_CONSUMPTION = 1;
var ENEMY_STRENGTH = 10;
var SURVIVOR_STRENGTH = 1;
//equations
this.FOOD_CONSUMPTION = (this.food - this.surviors);
this.raid = if ( EVENT_TYPE > 0.50);{
this.survivors - Math.floor((Math.random() * this.surviors) + 1);
};
```

Let me know if I left anything important out

Note: I copied this post from the game development stack exchange, because they had advised me it is more of a stack overflow question, as it relates more to JS as a whole, than game development.

Comment: it's not valid js `this.raid = if ( EVENT_TYPE > 0.50);{
this.survivors - Math.floor((Math.random() * this.surviors) + 1);
};`

Comment: I suggest working through some more JavaScript tutorials and/or a good solid beginner's book before posting more questions like this on SO. You want to get through the absolute basics first. Good luck and happy learning!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm going through the code academy course, and watching the occasional video in between, but yeah, this may be a little _too_ ambitious for my current level, I only know the very barest of the bones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a statement as the right-hand side of an assignment, which is what you're trying to do here:

```
this.raid = if ( EVENT_TYPE > 0.50);{
    this.survivors - Math.floor((Math.random() * this.surviors) + 1);
};
```

If you want to set `this.raid` to the result of `EVENT_TYPE > 0.50`, you just do that directly:

```
this.raid = EVENT_TYPE > 0.50;
```

If you then want to use that in a branch, you can follow it with the `if` testing `this.raid`:

```
this.raid = EVENT_TYPE > 0.50;
if (this.raid) {
    this.survivors - Math.floor((Math.random() * this.survivors) + 1);
}
```

*(I also fixed a typo in that, the second `survivors` was missing a `v`. But there's still a problem I didn't know how to fix: It calculates a value without storing it anywhere. It's not an **error** in JavaScript, but it probably isn't what you wanted. You may have meant `-=` instead of `-`.)*

Note that neither of the `;` that were originally in that `if` belonged there. You don't put `;` after the `()` in an `if`, and you don't put a `;` after the block attached to a flow-control statement (`if`, `while`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

1. You have a semicolon after the condition
2. To conditionally assign a variable you need to use the ternary operator, for example:

   ```
   const thing = condition ? ifTrue : ifFalse;
   ```

Or for your code:

```
this.raid = EVENT_TYPE > 0.50 ?
  this.survivors - Math.floor((Math.random() * this.surviors) + 1) :
  null;
//replace the null with what you want the variable to be if the condition is false
```